# jquery mobile doesn't refresh objects

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with three sections:
 
sections A,B,C

On section A there is a set of buttons that makes an Ajax request which updates section C. Up until here everything works fine.

The problem is that my buttons on section C (some links with `data-role="button"`) don't appear as buttons - but instead they are displayed as traditional links.

How can I do to change the links appearance to jQuery buttons?

```
<div id="setcionA">
    *** Here i call an mvc actionresult that return a partial view that update sectionC 
    <div class="nn" id="I_421" style="left: 0.06em; top: 0.06em; width: 5.18em; height: 5.5em;" onclick="loadXMLDoc('http://localhost:9063/Documentos/Docs/DocsAddItem?NumIdConcepto=421&NumCantidad=1','sectionC','0','POST');">
</div>
<div id="setcionB">
</div>

<div id="setcionC">
    *** This is the result of the ajax call .. but it appear as a link instead of a jquery mobile button
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a id="yes" href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the list was retrieved via ajax, it must be initialized

```
$('#ListView').listview(); // It Initializes
$('#ListView').listview('refresh'); // Refresh the list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me (other than misspelling the word "section" in your divs). It must be a problem with something else in your code not shown here.

EDIT: With jQuery mobile, doing what youre trying to accomplish, you would be better off refreshing the entire page with the new content rather than changing the page with Ajax.

Comment: All my other pages works as i expect.... My problemas are with the pages that need to partial update with ajax..  Very tks for your time.

Comment: Really  I don't know i'm new on Jquery .. all i Did is to add jquery mobile reference at _layout.cshtml .. what else i need to do to "refresh" a tag ? or to force it to change their appereance? TKS

Comment: mmm...the entire page? even if I only need to refresh a litle portion of them ?.... well if this is the better solution can you help me please with how can I do that ? it would be possible to do it acomplished with a transition ? TKS

Comment: Honestly without seeing more of your code and what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to give you an optimal solution.

Comment: All i need is : when update innerhtml of any div it takes the appareance configurated with jQueryMobile such as Button `    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
        <a id="yes" href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a> 
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a> 
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a> 
    </div> 
 ` must show three jQuery buttons instead three traditional links.